# Converting a particular type of json string in android

Tags: javascript, android, json

I have a json in this format

```
var list=[{"Name":"arun","City":"xyx","CountryName":"KUWAIT"},"Name":"Amal","City":"abb","CountryName":"BAHRAIN"}];
```

which is received from my web server to my android app as a String value, which I need to convert it into proper json format. The length of the string may become large according to the conditions. I have seen and converted json Strings and json arrays received only in this format:

```
{"Android":[{"slno":"1","name":"abc","number1":"123","number2":"456"},{"slno":"2","name":"def","number1":"789","number2":"000"},{"slno":"3","name":"","number1":"234","number2":"567"},{"slno":"4","name":"ghi","number1":"890","number2":"345"}]}
```

But I donot know how to convert the first json string received in my android app. How do I convert it in my app. 
  How do I convert it? Please help me

Comment: have you tried createing a Class with those var for example public String Name  , public String city , which json are you using in Android?>

Comment: The first seems to be invalid json

Comment: are you missing `{` before `"Name":"Amal"`??

Comment: @Raghunandan. Sorry there is a `{` before `"Name":"Amal"`...It is a valid json...

Comment: @ItzikSamara I got the solution for this problem from one of my friends..

Comment: @TeeJay posted a solution but what do you mean by convert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by convert. I assume you want to parse the json considering

```
[ // JSONArray node
    {  // JSONObject node index 0
        "Name": "arun", // key value pair.
        "City": "xyx",
        "CountryName": "KUWAIT"
    },
    {                        // JSONObject node index 1
        "Name": "Amal",
        "City": "abb",
        "CountryName": "BAHRAIN"
    }
]
```

To parse

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("jsonstring");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
     JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.getJSONObject(i);
     String name = jb.getString("Name");
     String city = jb.getString("City");
     String cname = jb.getString("CountryName"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to make HTTP request (for the `url` pass in your url)

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 500);

Client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
httpget = new HttpGet(url);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
mContent = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

Then use this to get your data:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mContent);
String firstname = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
String id = jsonObject.getString("Name"");
String headline = jsonObject.getString("City");
String lastName = jsonObject.getString("CountryName");
```

Then put it inside **asynctask**

---

### FINAL CODE::

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button btn;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            // because we implement OnClickListener we only have to pass "this"
            // (much easier)
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // detect the view that was "clicked"
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                new LongOperation().execute("");
                break;
            }
        }

        private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 500);

               Client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
               httpget = new HttpGet(url);
               ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
               mContent = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);


              JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mContent);
              String firstname = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
              String id = jsonObject.getString("Name"");
              String headline = jsonObject.getString("City");
               String lastName = jsonObject.getString("CountryName");


                return "Executed";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
                txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
                // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
                // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
        }
    }
```

***Let me know if you have problems in debugging***